# Has Bruce Wayne ever impersonated Nightwing?

Tags: dc, batman, secret-identity, nightwing

In most Batman media at one point in time or another a situation arises where both Batman and Bruce Wayne need to be seen together. While this has been accomplished by both Alfred and Superman, in recent years the go to person to portray Batman in Bruce's place would be Dick Grayson, aka Nightwing. But, has this dynamic (pun intended) ever gone the other way, where both Dick and Nightwing need to be seen together with Bruce filling the black and blue (or red) tights?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Given the relationship issues between Bruce Wayne and Dick Grayson which led to the creation of Nightwing, it is very unlikely Batman would ever wear the Nightwing outfit unless specifically asked by Grayson. There are no known incidents of Bruce Wayne wearing the Nightwing outfit.

- In the previous continuity where the character Nightwing was created, it was Grayson's attempt to step away from Batman's plan for him to inherit the Mantle of the Bat.
- Grayson wanted a heroic identity which he could make his own allowing him to quest for justice without becoming a crazed vigilante which he (at the time) considered Batman to be, at least some of the time. It also explains his reluctance to wear the Mantle during the time when Bruce Wayne was presumed dead.
- This isn't to say there couldn't be a circumstance where Wayne would wear the outfit and imitate Grayson's fighting style (because he could). In my knowledge, it just hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Did he ever impersonate Robin?

Comment: No, but he did try to hid his identity from one of his teachers using a prototype of the Robin costume. It was unsuccessful. He later gives the design to young Dick Grayson after making a few revisions for the Flying Grayson aerialist costume...

Comment: Gotta love a Thaddeus answer. Always the best.

Comment: It was always my understanding that Bruce was a bit larger than Dick. I could see where padding would allow Alfred or Dick to imitate Bruce, but not the other way around.

Comment: @Omegacron maybe if someone had the opportunity to scrutinize them that closely, but chances are the situation would be very brief.

Comment: If Grayson were willing and needed an alibi he could always arrange Batman or Jason Todd to stand in for him for a brief time (and at a good distance). Both, if they used smoke grenades for cover, could resemble Nightwing sufficiently to create reasonable doubt in anyone who is not extremely martially trained. It would not fool Bane, Shiva or Ra's Al Ghul, but it would at least confuse the average FBI, Interpol or other government lackey who just can't be bothered enough to pay that level of attention.

Comment: The more I think about it the more Jason seems like he would be a better choice to fill in for Dick. Or possibly even Tim Drake if he were to wear lifts in his boots to make him appear slightly taller.